# How do I detect overflow on a sum of integers using Rayon?

Tags: parallel-processing, rust, rayon

Is there a way to detect an overflow in Rayon and force it to panic instead of having an infinite loop?

```
extern crate rayon;

use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let sample: Vec<u32> = (0..50000000).collect();
    let sum: u32 = sample.par_iter().sum();

    println!("{}",sum );
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=02fdafb287c608c26145d1723a392402&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: It's not an infinite loop, it just takes a while to sum 50 million integers. Especially if it has to handle failure so many times in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`ParallelIterator::try_reduce`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.2/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.try_reduce). The documentation example does what you are looking for (and more):

> ```
> use rayon::prelude::*;
>
> // Compute the sum of squares, being careful about overflow.
> fn sum_squares<I: IntoParallelIterator<Item = i32>>(iter: I) -> Option<i32> {
>     iter.into_par_iter()
>         .map(|i| i.checked_mul(i))            // square each item,
>         .try_reduce(|| 0, i32::checked_add)   // and add them up!
> }
> assert_eq!(sum_squares(0..5), Some(0 + 1 + 4 + 9 + 16));
>
> // The sum might overflow
> assert_eq!(sum_squares(0..10_000), None);
>
> // Or the squares might overflow before it even reaches `try_reduce`
> assert_eq!(sum_squares(1_000_000..1_000_001), None);
> ```

Specifically for your example:

```
extern crate rayon;

use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let sample: Vec<u32> = (0..50000000).collect();
    let sum = sample
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(Some)
        .try_reduce(
            || 0, 
            |a, b| a.checked_add(b)
        );

    println!("{:?}", sum);
}
```

The `collect` is unneeded inefficiency, but I've left it for now.